# Speeding search of row that matches two conditions such as which(...&...) in R

Tags: r

I am looking to speeding up the little piece of code in R (see below) that searches the row # of the elements of table 1 that matches the ones of table2. Note that the which condition has an & because I need the two elements x & y to be identical in order for the row to be selected.

My data set is huge and this for loop is supper slow. Is there a way to speed this up ?

```
    mycoord<-c()
    for(k in 1:length(table2)){
           mycoord<-c(mycoord, 
                      which(table1$x==table2$x[k] & table1$y==table2$y[k]))
          }
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply merge the two tables by *x* and *y* and interact with merged output as needed.

```
merged_table <- merge(table1, table2, by=c("x", "y"))
```

All merged columns are then available as vectors:

```
merged_table$column1
merged_table$column2
merged_table$column3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In R a `for` loop over rows is extremly slow in case of big data sizes.

R offers vectorized methods instead and the great `data.table` package.

Your search is a "join" with two join columns.

Since you did not provide input data and the expected output I have created a simple example using the `mtcars` data set to show how to join:

```
library(data.table)

table2 = as.data.table(mtcars)
table1 = data.table(cyl = c(4, 6), gear = c(4, 3))

table2[table1, .SD, on = .(cyl, gear)]
```

`.SD` means "all columns" in this case and `on` specifies the columns to compare ("join columns").

`table1` contains the "look-up" data (= filter criteria for `table2`):

```
> table1
   cyl gear
1:   4    4
2:   6    3
```

Comment: I think without .SD also it will give the same result.

Comment: Yes, not using `.SD` works too in this example (and reduces the complexity to understand the result). If `table1` contains more columns `.SD` is required if you do want to have only the `table2` columns in the output instead of all columns of both tables so the usage depends on the purpose (filter or enrich via join)...